# Detecting when a file is saved

Tags: java

How can I notice when the execution of a txt file is closed and saved? I run the following code and I want to get the modified file.

This is my code

```
byte[] filedata = (byte[]) server.downloadFile(fileName);

//geting the file
File file = new File(userName+fileName+".txt");
BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(new   
        FileOutputStream(file.getName()));
output.write(filedata,0,filedata.length);
output.flush();
output.close();

//file.setWritable(true);
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("notepad "+userName+fileName+".txt");
```

Then I execute and when the users saves it with new data I want to get it here.

Comment: Please reformat this as readable code.

Comment: how to post my code with colors and everthing?

Answer (score 2):

rt.exec returns a Java Process object, which has a method to wait for the process to exit. I've never tried this myself (full disclosure) but I think this ought to work:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = rt.exec("notepad "+userName+fileName+".txt");
try {
  p.waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
  throw ex;
}
```